# how do you call Blocks in Controller Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I want `getBlock Adb/Block/Index in controller Adb/Controller/Category/View`. So How do it?

**Edit**

*in controller.*

```
namespace Addon\Faq\Controller\Category;


class View extends \Addon\Faq\Controller\Category
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory ;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry

    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory  = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Product list page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {   
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory ->create();
        $blockInstance = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('category.index');

    }
}
```

**layout in frontend**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Addon\Faq\Block\Faq" name="category.index" template="Addon_Faq::view.phtml"/>               
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

It not call block Faq

Comment: You should not call blocks in controller. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your return nothing in your execute command. Return resultpage in your controller

```
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

    return $resultPage;
```

your xml name should be faq_category_view.xml.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to instantiate a block you need to add to inject in the constructor an instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory`

```
...
protected $layoutFactory;
...
public function __construct(
   ...
   \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
   ...
) {
   ...
   $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
   ...
}
```

Then you can instantiate a block like this:

```
$this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock('Block\Class\Here');
```

if you want to access a block defined in the layout you need to inject in the constructor and instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory`

```
...
protected $resultPageFactory;
...
public function __construct(
   ...
   \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
   ...
) {
   ...
   $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
   ...
}
```

Then you will be able to access the block like this:

```
$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
$blockInstance = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('block.name.here');
```

Comment: is this still the *recommended* way of calling the block? Can I not inject? :)

Answer (score 9):

1. Create the block:

   ```
    <?php
       namespace Training\Test\Block;
       class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
       {
          protected function _toHtml() {
            return "<b>Hello world from block!</b>";
          }
       }
   ```
2. Create an action class:

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Training\Test\Controller\Block;
   class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
      {
      public function execute() {
        $layout = $this->_view->getLayout();
        $block = $layout->createBlock('Training\Test\Block\Test');
        $this->getResponse()->appendBody($block->toHtml());
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Do not use `$this->_view` in controllers. I read it is  `@deprecated`. Use `resultPage->getLayout()` instead like the other answer suggests.

Comment: Looks More Comprehensive

Answer (score 5):

See the core code:

#### Step 1

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/02e0378c33054acb0cdb8d731d1e2b2c2069bc1b/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php#L26-L34

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}
```

#### Step 2

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/02e0378c33054acb0cdb8d731d1e2b2c2069bc1b/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php#L69-L70

```
/** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
```

#### Step 3

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/02e0378c33054acb0cdb8d731d1e2b2c2069bc1b/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php#L119

```
$block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.wysiwyg.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the block and nothing else not sure if these answers are out of date but this worked for me.

```
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    protected $http;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Http $http
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->http = $http;
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $layout = $resultPage->getLayout();
        $block = $layout->createBlock('PixieMedia\AddPopup\Block\Addpopup\Paypal')
            ->setTemplate('PixieMedia_AddPopup::addpopup/paypal.phtml');
        return $this->http->setBody(
            $block->toHtml()
        );
    }
```

Comment: How can I specify layout via this method, i.e, in my case 'addpopup/paypal.phtml' has  different child block specified for catalog_product_view layout and cart layout