# Right way of calling Block in controller magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks

I need to call my custom class like below as it is done in `magento 1x`:

I need to Generate New Layered Navigation Menu

```
$viewPanel = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml(); 

$productList = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list')->toHtml();
```

Should i use `pageFactory` like as:

```
$viewPanel= $resultPageFactory->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct');
```

Or use:

```
$viewPanel= $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Tagalys\Tglcatalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
```

and **_view** is from `use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;` ?

Which is correct way of calling ?

Comment: Refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87629/how-do-call-block-in-controller-magento2

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way to use `$this->resultFactory`. And yes, Magento itself use `$this->_view` but it's the old way, It was @deprecated too but when M2 GA available they just remove (@deprecated) from `$this->_view`.

[For more information click here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1583)